# Can sentiment classification problem be resolved using regression?

Tags: python, regression, classification, text-classification

I have a data set of tweets, where each tweet has an average confidence score. 
For example
`Tweet`                      `Average Confidence`  `Standard Deviation`

`too much thoughts inside his headdd we can t even imagine` `0.3`  `0.163951`

`His ass need to stay up` `0.8` `0.161962`

`First time I heard his name in camp, he seems amazing` `0.19` `0.181962`

Average Confidence is the average of the confidences predicted by several supervised models for a specific instance to belong to the positive class.

Standard Deviation is the confidences' standard deviation from Average Confidence for a particular instance.

If i consider it as a regression task, how to handle multi label data

EDIT
[image: Data set]

Comment: what's your goal?

Comment: i want to classify whether tweet is positive or not. but lables are like regression problem. so i think i should go for regression, so i can tell what is confidence of unlabeled tweet.. but  i am confused

Comment: it still not clear what do you want to do? what are your multi labels? and how and why do you want to introduce regression to a NLP model (usually a neural network)

Comment: i have attached the image of dataset

Comment: You seem to assume that there is a way to reach 100% accuracy on understanding human language just by tweaking the model and its parameters. This is still very far from the truth. Sentiment classification is still very imprecise on individual utterances. It makes sense when you have enough correctly classified utterances so that their signal dominates over the noise of imprecise classification.

Comment: still your use case is unclear... what are you considered as multi labels? and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: ok, i am considering average and std as multilabels, becuase we need to feed both of these columns as labels

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understood your question quite yet, so answered as best I thought :)

Basically the **score** (in your case `average`) is used alone in sentiment analysis to classify good-bad sentences (data), pick a threshold which yield the best classification results, lets say `0.6` so

```
if score >= 0.6
  classify as GOOD
else
  classify as BAD
```

I suggest to see if this simple approach is good enough for your requirements

in case you want to classify using more variables (information) e.g 'average`and`std` you can use another classification model (like **logistic-regression**, **decision trees**, **svm** and more...)

in case you would like to use some regression approach, I suggest a [logistic regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) (it's pretty strait forward)

because your current model consists of just 2 variables `average` and `std` a **svm**, might give better results (basically it project the data on higher dimension and do the classification there)

keep in mind all methods (maybe except decision-trees and such) will output another score, like prob of classification between `0` to `1` so a thresholds will always have to be applied at the end